# Scraping oddly formatted numbers using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an HTML table using `BS4` Python, but for numbers formatted like this `247 759 384` (`read as 247759384`) in the HTML are appearing differently in python. I would like to output them as they are in the table.

```
temp = []
a = soup.findAll('tr')[1]
for td in a.find_all("td"):
    temp.append(str(td.text))
    #print(str(td.text))
a.findAll('td')[10].text
```

gives me an output of

```
'24\xa0081\xa0728'
```

instead of

```
24081728
```

Comment: What is the encoding you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if your characters are numbers using `isnumeric()`

```
string='24\xa0081\xa0728'
''.join(e for e in string if e.isnumeric())
'24081728'
```

Comment: I guess this should be the encoding issue. Instead of manipulating string, by using the right encoding will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `\xa0` is a [no-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) in unicode.

A quick way to fix it is just to replace it with an ascii space (using say `string.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')`). But be careful, there may be other encoding issues you haven't spotted yet.

I'd recommend reading [this](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html) first and handle it in a cleaner way.